# What happens when rocksdb can't flush a memtable to a sst file?

Tags: rocksdb

Our service (which uses rockdb) was out of disk space for approximately 30 minutes.
We manually deleted some files which freed-up 650MiB.
However, even with those free 650MiB, rocksdb kept complaining:

> IO error: Failed to pwrite for:
>   /path/to/database/454250.sst: There is not enough space on the disk.

Is it possible that the memtable got so big that it needed more than 650MB of disk space?
Looking at other sst files in the database folder, they don't take up more than ~40MiB.

If not, what other reasons could there be for these error messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two cases where this can happen,

1) Rocksdb persists the in-memory data via WAL files and it gets removed when the memtable is flushed. When you have multiple column families, where some of them have higher insert rates (memtable fills faster) and others have lower rates, the `.log files` (rocksdb WAL files) cannot be removed. This is because, the wal files contain transactions from all column families and it cannot be removed until all the column families have been persisted via a flush. 
This might lead to stagnant .log files resulting in Disk space issues.

2) Assume, the memtable size is configured to be 1GB and the number to memtables to merge is 3, 
you actually wait for 3 memtables to fill and then the flush gets triggerred. Even if you had configured the target file size (since you had mentioned your SSTs are around 40MB) to 50MB, you will generate 185 SSTs each of size 50MB totalling 3GB.
But the space you have is around 650MB which might be a problem.

There are various options that influence the flush behaviour in rocksdb. you can take a look at,

`write_buffer_size` - Size of each memtable.

`min_write_buffer_number_to_merge` - Number of memtables to merge during a flush or in other words, when the immutable memtable count becomes equal to this value, do a flush to disk.

`target_file_size_base` - Size of the resulting SSTs from compaction or Flush.

`target_file_size_multiplier` - Decides the Size of SSTs in each level.

You can also take a look at SST compression techniques. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Hello, 

I am facing a similar kind of problem. Our service disk usage was very high and WAL files were piled up. After restarting the service on one of the nodes, the disk usage was reduced. Now the WAL files are getting piled up again and disk usage is increasing.

Comment: We have ~50 column family and the following RocksDB properties:
CF.compaction_style 1
CF.level0_file_num_compaction_trigger 10
CF.level0_slowdown_writes_trigger 40
CF.max_bytes_for_level_base 800MB
CF.max_write_buffer_number 10
CF.memtable_prefix_bloom_size_ratio 0.125
CF.optimize_for_point_lookup false
CF.optimize_for_point_lookup.block_cache_size_mb 50
CF.optimize_for_small_db false
CF.report_bg_io_stats false
CF.target_file_size_base 256MB
CF.write_buffer_size 256MB
RO.readaheadSize 10MB
Table.block_cache_capacity 800MB
Table.block_size 64KB
enable_lru_cache true